# Google Apps Script Run Installable Trigger on Custom Menu Item Click

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Is it possible to set an installable trigger that runs when users select an option from a custom menu in Google Sheets? I need it to be an installable trigger in order to run with the permissions of the creator versus with those of the user behind the keyboard.

Edit:

`ScriptApp.newTrigger()` documentation lists the following example

```
// Creates an edit trigger for a spreadsheet identified by ID.
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_a1b2c3')
    .onEdit()
    .create();
```

Here it seems that it is set to call a custom function whenever the spreadsheet is edited. This does not seem to address how to create a trigger that fires when a user selects a custom menu item.

Comment: Look at ScriptApp.newTrigger()

Comment: @Cooper I looked it up in the docs and  wasn't able to figure out how they would help. Added some details.

Comment: Have you searched for how to create menu and chain it to a function?

Comment: Try SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu()

Comment: Thanks for the help folks. The problem is not creating a menu (I got that part covered). The tricky part is actually executing an installable trigger vs just creating it on the menu item press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can not make a trigger fire by clicking on a custom menu item in Sheets. You can however utilise a Web App to execute a function as another person from a custom menu item.*

<sub>***NB:*** *This answer was edited after more information was provided, the original answer is below the break.*</sub>

#### More Information:

As a preface, I'd just like to go over what triggers actually are. Google Apps Script has two kinds of triggers, [Simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and [Installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). From the documentation on Simple Triggers:

> Triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, like opening a document, occurs.

and from the Installable Triggers documentation:

> Like simple triggers, installable triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, such as opening a document, occurs. Installable triggers, however, offer more flexibility than simple triggers: they can call services that require authorization, they offer several additional types of events including time-driven (clock) triggers, and they can be controlled programmatically.

Triggers are exactly that - they work similarly to [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to execute code when a very specific type of action happens, like a Sheet is edited or the time hits 2pm. It isn't possible to force a trigger to fire under any circumstance other than the one it was set up to do.

#### The Workaround:

The Apps Script environment provides a way of executing code as yourself regardless of the person that calls it - [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Firstly, you will need to create a second project which contains the code that you wish to execute on button click, inside a function called `doGet()` (this is another kind of [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#dogete_and_doposte)):

```js
function doGet(e) {
  console.log("Menu item clicked!");
}
```

From here, you will need to publish the script as a Web App. Follow the `Publish > Deploy as web app...` menu item, and set up the configutation as follows:

- **Project version:** `New`
- **Execute the app as:** `Me (email@address.dom)`
- **Who has access to the app:** `Anyone, even anonymous`

And Hit `Deploy`. This will give you a Web App URL in a text box which you can copy.

Now going back to your Sheet with the custom menu, you can make a call to your Web App URL using `UrlFetch` to execute the code inside the `doGet(e)` function that you set up:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/a/somedomain.com/macros/s/some-web-app-id/exec");
}
```

**Rundown of this code:**

- When the Spreadsheet is opened, the `onOpen()` method is called, creating a new menu item in the UI's toolbar.

  - This `onOpen()` method adds the menu item `Custom Menu > First item`. The function `menuItem1` is assigned to run when this menu item is clicked.
- The function `menuItem1` will then make a fetch call to the web app you created in the first step, executing the code in its `doGet(e)` function as you - the person that set up the Web App, as per the Web App's configuration.

Things to remember:

- You will need to first authorise your code so that it runs when the menu item is selected.
- As per [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/154161164), when you authenticate the script by clicking on the menu item, ***it will not run the first time the menu item is clicked.*** You will have to invoke it a second time after you have authorised the script.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

  - [`doGet(e)` and `doPost(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#dogete_and_doposte)
- [Installable | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [cron - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)
- [EventListener - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)
- [Web Apps | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

---

#### Answer:

*This is absolutely possible!*

#### More Information:

You're most of the way there with the code snippet you have - what you need to do from here is call this script when a menu item in the UI is called. You can see an example of using custom menus in G Suite [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

#### Code Example:

You will need to use the `newTrigger()` method as you have shown in your question, in conjunction with the custom menu item functions:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet('your-spreadsheet-id')
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}

function myFunction() {
  // do some stuff
}
```

**Rundown of this code:**

- When the Spreadsheet is opened, the `onOpen()` method is called, creating a new menu item in the UI's toolbar.

  - This `onOpen()` method adds the menu item `Custom Menu > First item`. The function `menuItem1` is assigned to run when this menu item is clicked.
- The function `menuItem1` creates an installable `onEdit()` trigger when called. This trigger will fire the function `myFunction()` whenever the Spreadsheet is edited.
- The function `myFunction()` is whatever you want your installable `onEdit` to do.

#### References:

- [Custom Menus in G Suite | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Sheet-bound app script doesn't run after authorizing, 2nd run works OK - Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/154161164)

Comment: I'd like the menu item press to actually execute the trigger. Seems the code creates an onEdit trigger that gets executed when the user edits the spreadsheet which is different.

Comment: I don't see why you need to do this... Rather than executing the trigger, why don't you just run the function that the trigger runs?

Comment: Because I need the function to run under my permissions (the creator). If I just run the function directly it will run under the permissions of the user behind the keyboard.

Comment: @user1114 You can't run triggers in this way (from menu click) but you can do what you want with a Web App. I'll write up a workaround shortly.

Comment: @user1114 Answer updated, let me know if there's anything else I can do to help